# c# selenium chrome-webdrive clicking button using class and title

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, chrome-web-driver

i just want to click button in my page. 
The html code lookls like :

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection" ng-class="{ &quot;error-row&quot;: row.errorMessage }" ng-style="vm.getColor(row)" class="ng-scope" style="background: rgb(255, 242, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">
    <td class="ng-binding">Wylaczenie nadan RDF</td><td class="ng-binding">WAITING_FOR_NOTIFICATION</td>
    <td>
        <a href="" ng-click="vm.showProcessDiagram(row.executor)" class="ng-binding">rfsSendingExecutor</a>
    </td>
    <td class="ng-binding">2017-09-06 11:14:12</td><td class="ng-binding">2017-09-06 11:14:13</td>
    <td has-role="REQUEST" class="text-center">
    <!-- ngIf: row.inXml || row.outXml -->
    <button ng-if="row.inXml || row.outXml" ng-click="vm.showXml(row)" title="Show" class="btn btn-xs ng-scope"><span class="fa fa-code"></span></button>
    <!-- end ngIf: row.inXml || row.outXml -->
    </td>
    <td has-role="ERROR" class="text-center"><button ng-show="row.errorMessage" ng-click="vm.showError(row.errorMessage)" title="Show" class="btn btn-xs ng-hide"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button></td>
    <td class="text-center">
    <button ng-show="vm.enableCancel(row)" ng-click="vm.cancelTask(row.workItemId)" title="Cancel" class="btn btn-xs ng-hide">
        <span class="fa fa-ban text-warning"></span>
    </button> 
    <button ng-show="vm.enableRepeat(row)" ng-click="vm.repeatTask(row.id)" title="Repeat" class="btn btn-xs ng-hide">
        <span class="fa fa-refresh text-success"></span>
    </button> 
    <button ng-show="vm.enableRepeat(row)" ng-click="vm.repeatTaskWithParams(row.id)" title="Repeat with parameters" class="btn btn-xs ng-hide">
        <span class="fa fa-refresh text-warning"></span>
    </button>
    <button ng-show="vm.enableSkip(row)" ng-click="vm.skipTask(row.workItemId)" title="Skip" class="btn btn-xs">
        <span class="fa fa-angle-double-right text-success"></span>
    </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

All i want to do is click this button :

```
<button ng-show="vm.enableSkip(row)" ng-click="vm.skipTask(row.workItemId)" title="Skip" class="btn btn-xs">
        <span class="fa fa-angle-double-right text-success"></span>
```

I've been through the xpath tutorials and checked many other posts nad forums. I'm not sure what I'm missing. I'm simply trying to find the following element by xpath like this :

```
button_to_click= findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Skip']"));
```

but it doesn't work.  **QUESTION :** Why it don't work only by title?
I try another way and do like that :

```
 button_to_click= findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-xs']"));
```

And it works well , but when i have 3 or 4 elements in this class it just press wrong button.
How can i press exacly this button  can someone help me?
Maybe shouold i try something like this?

```
button_to_click= findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-xs']//button[@title='Skip']"));
```

*Why it don't work only by title? And how can i do that better? Please be patient for newbies.*

**EDIT 1**
I add more code as you want to know what I'm doing. :
 This code works well :

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.url ="http://mypage.com"
button_to_click= findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-xs']")).Click();
```

And this code doesn't work :

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.url ="http://mypage.com"
button_to_click= findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Skip']")).Click();
```

**EDIT 2**
I will give you an example page for testing. You just have to download the html file and open it in your browser.[Html page file](https://ufile.io/edkck)
What we now want to do? 
If you run this html file you will see all page. 
And now we want to make a Click on exacly this button on screen :
[image]
After when you click on this button you will see click counter below : like this :
[image]
Have anyone idea how to click it? I try few ways and can't find solution still. Please help.

**EDIT 3**

I try also : - but it too doesn't work

```
drive.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[class='ng-scope']/td[text()='Wylaczenie nadan RDF'] and button[@title='Skip'']]")).Click();
```

Comment: Noticed that the button is in a table row.  Do you have multiple instances of the button on the page. Also could you show more of your c# code to get an idea of what you are trying to do

Comment: I find it strange that xpath("//button[@title='Skip']") doesnt work. And by reversing: xpath('//button[@title="Skip"]') ? I know it's the same but maybe ??

Comment: Yes, i have multiple instances of the button on the page. I'm trying just to click button which contains title='Skip' .

Comment: please check EDIT 1 in main post i added more code for example i alsbo try using  - ng-click="vm.skipTask(row.workItemId) and ng-show="vm.enableSkip(row)" but doesn't work as like title.

Comment: I don't think that the "title" tag is the problem. Because your xpath is correct.
For example in: http://php.wekeepcoding.com/article/18943879/Use+xpath+or+xquery+to+show+text+in+title+attribute , //*[@title="xpath"] works

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this - > if (button_to_click= findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-xs']")); ) =  true and  inside it visible @title='Skip' then just click it? I don't have idea how can i just do that

Comment: I spent 3-4 days and still can't find solution to do that can canyone help? Please Check EDIT  2 . i add there example page when you can download and test it own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your Question, this line of code works :

```
button_to_click= findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-xs']")).Click();
```

This line of code does't works :

```
button_to_click= findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Skip']")).Click();
```

### Explanation:

Looking at the `HTML DOM` it's clear the `WebApplication` uses a lot of **`JavaScript`** & **`Ajax Calls`**. Hence are the attributes e.g. **`ng-repeat`**, **`ng-class`** etc with dynamic values e.g. **`{ &quot;error-row&quot;: row.errorMessage }`**, **`vm.showError(row.errorMessage)`** etc. So it will be tough to use these values/attributes to construct an `xpath` or `CSSselector`

Using `xpath` as `//button[@title='Skip']` should have worked provided the `xpath` uniquely identified the specific element of our interest. But as it is not happening I suspect there may be multiple elements matching this `xpath` where some of them may be disabled/hidden. So, the `xpath` using the `title` attribute as **`Skip`** `FAILED`.

Using `xpath` as `//button[@class='btn btn-xs']` works without failure because here we have considered the **`class`** attribute which is extensively used within `CSSselector` as well as within `xpath` which maps down to querySelector/querySelectorAll. Hence, this option is more reliable and works perfect.

### Update :

Though using `xpath` as **`//button[@class='btn btn-xs']`** works for you without any failure I am not sure why you want to avoid it. About the `xpath` you mentioned in your comment, as you have got much granular in your search using the `<button>` tag it seems unnecessary to reference any parent node e.g. `tr[text()='Wylaczenie nadan RDF']`. Incase `xpath` as **`//button[@class='btn btn-xs']`** doesn't identifies the element uniquely you can consider to club up the `class` and `title` attribute as follows:

```
button_to_click= findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-xs' and @title='Skip']")).Click();
```

Comment: You are right. Would you like to write it as it should look to click that button? //tr[text()='Wylaczenie nadan RDF']/button[@title='Skip']  Is that enough?

Comment: As i see it's very good answear. Let me ask the last thing. But  when i just want to do something like that : button_to_click= findElement(By.xpath("//tr[text()='Wylaczenie nadan RDF']/button[@class='btn btn-xs' and @title='Skip']")).Click();  Is that okay and should work the same?

Comment: OK i check it.  And this works fine : button_to_click= findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-xs' and @title='Skip']")).Click();  . But when i try just click button as i said in my EDIT 2  by this : button_to_click= findElement(By.xpath("//tr[text()='Wylaczenie nadan RDF']/button[@class='btn btn-xs' and @title='Skip']")).Click(); - it doesn't work , can you just help me and click this correct button? Your post is very good but it click 1st button in this class and this title that is't what i'm looking for. You can just check on this site i post in main post it doesn't work.

Comment: Check EDIT 3 also

Comment: Could you just help  me in another topic? I see you know a lot about it. Thank you very much. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611317/c-sharp-selenium-chrome-webdrive-write-advenced-path-chrome-driver

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious if you have an element higher in the dom with the same attributes and html elements as the XPath that you're attempting to select. Let's get super specific with our XPath and throw in some and conditions. Give this guy a shot:

```
//button[@ng-show='vm.enableSkip(row)' and @title='Skip' and @class='btn btn-xs']
```

If you need to add even more identifiers keep throwing them in there. There is nothing wrong with having very concrete XPaths.

It also looks like your button is in a table row. If there is anything unique in the tr element that contains the button you should definitely throw that in the xpath before the button and you wouldn't have to be concerned about it clicking a button in a previous tr, and in doing so you know you wouldn't need anything more than @title='Skip' for your uniqueness for the button portion of the XPath.

For example...

```
//tr[@attribute='uniqueTRValue']/button[@title='Skip']
```

Comment: Could you just look my example and try to Path exacly for this button as i said? Unique there is  "Wylaczenie nadan RDF" but is in subclass before than clicking button class

Comment: //tr[text()='Wylaczenie nadan RDF']/button[@title='Skip']

Comment: I'll check this when i back to home and code it then i replay here

Comment: Doesn't work - //tr[text()='Wylaczenie nadan RDF']/button[@title='Skip']