# c# selenium chrome-webdriver write advanced Path (chrome-driver)

Tags: c#, html, selenium, path, selenium-chromedriver

I just try to write correct path to click exactly this button what I want on my page. I will give you an example page for testing. You just have to download the HTML file and open it in your browser.[Code of HTML page](https://uploadfiles.io/edkck)
What we now want to do? 
If you run this HTML file you will see all page. 
And now we want to make a Click on exactly this button on screen :
[image]
After when you click on this button you will see click counter below: like this :
[image]

Have anyone idea how to click it? I tried few ways and can't find solution still. Please help.
I try at least :

```
drive.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[class='ng-scope']/td[text()='Wylaczenie nadan RDF'] and button[@title='Skip']")).Click();
```

and

```
drive.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[text()='Wylaczenie nadan RDF']/button[@title='Skip']")).Click();
```

+ more and more and can't just write fine this Path to click exacly this button.
And unique value is `<td class="ng-binding">Wylaczenie nadan RDF</td>` - i prefer to get path by this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# selenium chrome-webdrive clicking button using class and title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46601482/c-sharp-selenium-chrome-webdrive-clicking-button-using-class-and-title)

Comment: Do not post duplicate questions when you already have asked your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use below XPATH for the same

```
//tr[td='Wylaczenie nadan RDF']//button[@title='Skip']"
```

`//tr[td='Wylaczenie nadan RDF']` will take you to the row which contains that text and then you use `//button[@title='Skip']` to find that button

Comment: I already offered him this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46601482/c-sharp-selenium-chrome-webdrive-clicking-button-using-class-and-title/46606448?noredirect=1#comment80172207_46606448

Comment: @JonahOberloh, you needed `//button` instead of `/button`